How do I run npm install for a package in .tgz format that is hosted/committed on Gitlab?
I have an npm package that I have to be able to install from Gitlab (not npm registry, or any other registry).
I created a release branch called gitlab-release, where I ran npm pack to create a .tgz file.
When I have this in my pacakge.json, it gets the whole repo and puts it in node_modules:
"@team/ui-package": "git+https://gitlab-<corp>.net/<team>/<project>/ui-package#gitlab-release"

When I have this in my package.json, I get the following error:
"@team/ui-package": "https://gitlab-<corp>.net/<team>/<project>/ui-package/-/archive/gitlab-release/project-ui-package-9.2.0.tar.tgz."


npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: @team/ui-package@https://gitlab-<corp>.net/<team>/<project>/ui-package/-/archive/gitlab-release/project-ui-package-9.2.0.tar.tgz.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

The url by itself downloads the .tgz file.
When I try to use the local .tgz file, that I just downloaded, it works as expected.
How can I do npm install for a tgz file that is hosted in a Gitlab repo?

Maybe I'm wrong, but after checking your error message, it seems that the package.json file might be missing. Try checking if the package.json file is present at the root of the archive. If it's not, check if it's located in a subdirectory.

Thanks for reply :) Yes the error message says that, but when I expand the .tgz file, I see the package.json in the root directory

I think the issue is more about Non-registry package. I tried the same in Github with a dummy project, and same error.
